# erroneous output while using switch() with a char from vector string

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> v = {"a", "a", "a"};
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        switch(v[i][0]) {
            case 'a':
                cout<<"case a"<<"\n";
            case 'b':
                cout<<"case b"<<"\n";
            case 'c':
                cout<<"case c"<<"\n";

        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\calc>g++ test.cpp && a.exe

case a
case b
case c
case a
case b
case c
case a
case b
case c
```

Expected output:

```
case a
```

why is 'a' which is what `v[i][0]` would always be trigger all the three cases, I don't understand, isn't `v[i][0]` a char ?

Comment: You're missing `break;` statements.

Comment: The output is not erroneous, do you know the [`break`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break) keyword?

Comment: Pay closer attention to your fine C++ book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use "break" statement in each case.

```
switch(v[i][0]) {
            case 'a':
                cout<<"case a"<<"\n";
                break;
            case 'b':
                cout<<"case b"<<"\n";
                break;
            case 'c':
                cout<<"case c"<<"\n";
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Oh yeah !! Rookie mistake, thanks man